# Node.js Stream objectMode

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, stream, pipe, monads

I'm trying to understand the concept of object streams, especially the combination of both. The usage I'm looking for is piping byte streams together with object streams like:

```
// StringifyStream reads Buffers and emits String Objects
// Mapper is really just a classical map
// BytifyStream reads String Objects and emits buffers.

process.stdin.pipe(
   StringifyStream()
).pipe( 
   Mapper(function(s) {
      return s.toUpperCase();
}).pipe(
    BytifyStream()
).pipe(process.stdout);

// This code should read from stdin, convert all incoming buffers to strings,
// map those strings to upper case and finally convert them back to buffers
// and write them to stdout.
```

Now, the documentation says:

"Setting objectMode mid-stream is not safe."

I dont really understand what this means. Is mixing byte/object streams not safe ?? I would really like to use this pattern but if its not safe, it probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object streams are those that emit data types other than Buffer or String.

> Streams that are in object mode can emit generic JavaScript values other than Buffers and Strings.

Your example is safe, it just does the conversion Buffer -> string -> upper string -> Buffer.

This is only my opinion but you could simplify the chain and use only one [Transform](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform_1) stream.

```
var util = require ("util");
var stream = require ("stream");

var UpperStream = function (){
    stream.Transform.call (this);
};

util.inherits (UpperStream, stream.Transform);

UpperStream.prototype._transform = function (chunk, encoding, cb){
    this.push ((chunk + "").toUpperCase ());
    cb ();
};

process.stdin.pipe (new UpperStream ()).pipe (process.stdout);
```